# Why won't my jarsigner work?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, javac, jarsigner

For some reason why I try any command including just `jarsigner` it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.security.tools.JarSigner
```

Do I have an incorrect version of Java? I've re-installed Java many times and tried 64 bit and 32 bit versions. I have the newest version of the Java JDK (`Java 7 update 45`) on Windows 7. Also, my `javac` command gives me a similar error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

But, my `java` command doesn't.

My `PATH` includes the java jdk bin `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin`, Do I need anything else? My `CLASSPATH` is `.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` and I tried changing it to just `.` but that didn't work either. I also tried setting the variable to `Path` instead of `PATH` but the same error came out. I have searched many times in my `PATH` environment variable and there are no signs of the word `Java`. The bin above for my `PATH`is the only sign of the word `Java`. Right now I have my Java bin in my user environment variables. Do I need it in the system environment variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PATH is wrong, or it contains a bin directory from an obsolete or largely uninstalled JDK, or your CLASSPATH points to an obsolete JDK, or possibly a JRE. If either of the latter, remove that element from the PATH or CLASSPATH.

> What do I actually need for the CLASSPATH if I need anything.

There's no need for a CLASSPATH setting other than '.' as far as Java itself is concerned.